# moved to kde and get this response every reboot git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, kde, keyrings

I recently moved from xfce to kde, and now every time i reboot my computer i have to add my keys using ssh-add.
this are the steps i made every time

1. Boot and enter my session
2. make a "git pull"
3. Error
4. Add the key
5. git
6. reboot
7. has to do everything again